# VisualSVN Server: taking backups using svnadmin tool

Tags: svn, backup, windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN Server on Windows Server 2008. I was trying to create a hotcopy backup using svnadmin tool. It seems that I don't have this tool installed:

```
C:\>svnadmin hotcopy C:\Repositories\Develop C:\temp\svnbackup
'svnadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does VisualSVN Server include svnadmin tool? How can I get this tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the solution:

I have these tools in this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin. I just had to add this to path enviromental values.

Comment: VisualSVN Server adds it's path to environment variables. See %VISUALSVN_SERVER% variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to add the path to the environment variables. The reason why you got that error is because you are in C:\ but the SVN admin is in other location. Just traverse to the directory where it is located and do the same thing and it works.