# SVN server backup

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am not able to take svn server backup on Windows 8. I've already tried many commands which was given at StackOverflow but non of them worked so far. Can any one help me with this?

My working copy is located in `C:\working\sample` and the repository path is `E:\Repositories`.

I use the following command in svn command prompt:

`svnadmin hotcopy E:\Repositories E:\repo.back`

I'm getting the following error

```
svnadmin: E720002: Can't open file 'E:\repositories\format': The system cannot f
ind the file specified.
```

by giving the above command i observed repo.back file was created in e drive with 0kb

And more over pls tell me in which mode of the command prompt I should use this commands

Comment: I think you are supposed to backup one repository at a time with this command (e.g. `svnadmin hotcopy e:\repositories\something e:\something.back`), not all of them at once.

Comment: in which mode of the command prompt i need to give that command for example the repository is in e drive so do i need to change the directory to E:\ drive in command prompt and give that command ? because i have doubt on that

Comment: Current working directory should not matter. Here is the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977606/visualsvn-server-taking-backups-using-svnadmin-tool

Comment: I was getting an error which i mentioned above frequently by using that command.But this time i uninstalled and reinstalled visualsvn server and tried once again as you suggested by giving the command

Comment: Now it worked and no error and i found the bakup file was create in  my e drive but it was looking like normal folder then we can perform the copy paste task rite?why we want to use svnadmin command?

Comment: @mephi42 the link to other question is not about this case.

Answer (score 3):

> My working copy is located in C:\working\sample and the repository
>   path is E:\Repositories.

`E:\Repositories\` is the root location of your repositories, not a repository. [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.hotcopy.html) command makes a backup of a single repository, so you have to run the command like this `svnadmin hotcopy E:\Repositories\<reponame> E:\RepoBackup\<backupname>`.

There are [various ways to backup Subversion repos](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup), make sure to choose the one which fits your requirements best. I advise you to read my [other answer on the this topic at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/20514/what-ways-there-are-to-backup-repositories-for-windows-visualsvn/407493#407493).

PS I guess that this question is offtopic on StackOverflow and has to be asked on ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I would like to add that if you get an "Access is denied" error, then you can try running the "svnadmin hotcopy" as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to backup the entire svn repository system is to stop whichever server you have exposing it to clients, then make a copy of the root directory containing the repos. Once you're done, turn the server back on.

svnadmin hotcopy allows you to make backups of a running repo, ie while clients are accessing it.

svnsync will continually backup the repo in an incremental fashion and is the one I recommend, but if all you want si a quick snapshot to protect the repo (when you're upgrading or installing new stuff), then stop-copy-start is just as good.